# If you place a filled water bottle at the bottom of the Mariana Trench, how does the bottle stand the enormous pressure?

Tags: forces, pressure

**The pressures are akin to an entire train pressing down on you.**

*How does the water bottle stand this pressure?*

And yes, the water bottle will stand: How else do the creatures at the very bottom of the ocean survive? Just like us, they fill their bodies with the exact pressure as the outside.

The compressive strength of plastic is decidedly not of this strength. In fact, why do the sea creatures survive either? Are we to conclude that the delicate shells of the deep-sea shrimps may withstand pressures in excess of... megapascals? After all their shells are constantly being crushed by the gargantuan pressures **coming from both inside and outside.**

**I know that the pressure is evened out, coming from inside and outside, *so right now I can only conclude that the bottle/shell is being compressed a LOT*.** 
*Is there any other ways to resolve this problem?*

Another interesting thought: What if you filled it with water **from the surface?** Wouldn't the bottle be crushed because the water down at the Mariana Trench is more compressed? And vice versa?

Comment: Any empty bottle brought down from the surface would get crushed as the air compressed inside. The density change of water is only a few percent at the bottom of the Marianas Trench, so the bottle would deform a little bit. Your question is equivalent to asking how the water can possibly stand all that pressure, and it does so just fine by slightly changing the distance between molecules to balance out the forces. Just as in a steel plate, that can take many times the hydrostatic pressures encountered even at those depths.

Comment: this is equivalent to asking why does your head not implode under the enourmous preassure of $10^5 N/m^2$. Why don't you get crushed? You are in approximate preassure equilibrium with the atmosphere!

Comment: Re, _What if you filled it with water from the surface?_: Water is very stiff.  The change in volume would be enough to alter the bottle's shape a little, but not nearly enough to "crush" the bottle.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Compressibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in a sense: under the pressures of the Mariana Trench, the thin plastic of the bottle walls will become slightly thinner as it is squeezed between the water inside and outside. This does not mean that the bottle is "crushed" or will deform, and the effect is likely to be quite small, depending on the bottle material. The integrity of the bottle will only be threatened if the pressures are extreme enough to cause a phase change in its material.

Answer (score 2):

Water is almost incompressable, unlike air.

If you filled the bottle with air, then sent it into the Marianas Trench, then the bottle would crush until the pressure of the air inside matched that of the water outside.  At that point, the bottle would be almost (but not quite) flat.

If you fill the bottle with water, then the water inside cannot compress, and the pressure rapidly equalises.  The plastic of the bottle's walls will experience huge pressures from both inside and out, but most plastics are also incompressable as well.

Fish are generally full of water and incompressable solids (such as bones), so they can't be crushed either.

Comment: Does that mean that if you got a container made of highly compressible material and filled it with water and brought it to the Trench, you would see the container walls flatten out?

Comment: Re, _Fish are generally full of water_:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_bladder

Comment: @HyperLuminal if the material itself was squashy, such as neoprene, then it would squash very thin under the pressure.